# Trying to send an array in a circle through several ranks in MPI, but am getting seg faults. Can anyone please tell me why?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi

I'm trying to send an array from one process (rank) to another in a "circle" using MPI in C. I can get it to work just fine using single integers, but am getting segmentation faults when I try to send the array through.

```
{
int rank;
int numRanks;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numRanks);

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

int arraysize = 100;

int *array;

if (rank == 0) {
    array = malloc(sizeof(int)*arrasize);
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++) {
        array[i] = 1;
    }
    double starttime = MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Send(&array, arraysize, MPI_INT, (rank+1), 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(&array, arraysize, MPI_INT, numRanks-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    double endtime = MPI_Wtime();
    printf("Rank %d got array from Rank %d in %lf", rank, numRanks-1, endtime-starttime);
} else if (rank == (numRanks-1)) {
    MPI_Recv(&array, arraysize, MPI_INT, rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Rank %d got array from Rank %d", rank, rank-1);
    MPI_Send(&array, arraysize, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else {
    MPI_Recv(&array, arraysize, MPI_INT, rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Rank %d got array from Rank %d", rank, rank-1);
    MPI_Send(&array, arraysize, MPI_INT, (rank+1), 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

free(array);

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;

}
```

Here's the error message (I'm only using three ranks right now for simplicity):

```
Rank 1 got array from Rank 0
[winston:42137] *** Process received signal ***
[winston:42137] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[winston:42137] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[winston:42137] Failing at address: 0x7add28
```

and then more of the same for each rank trying to send and receive the array

any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: if you compile the program with the **-g** option and run it under **gdb**, it will stop when getting the segmentation fault and with the **bt** command you'll see where it happened.
**valgrind** is also another tool you should use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `array` is not pointing to a valid memory address in every process (rank) other than the 0-th.
This will make your program crash when trying to write something in a random (i.e. invalid) address, which is when you call `MPI_Recv(&array, arraysize...`.

(Thanks to Gilles Gouaillardet pointed out in the comment) And you should pass `array` (not `&array`) to MPI functions because itself is the pointer to an address where is allocated to you to store *some* `int`.

So, the solution will be:

1. Run `array = malloc(sizeof(int)*arrasize);` on every process.
2. Change `MPI_Recv(&array` (and `MPI_Send(&array`) to `MPI_Recv(array` (and `MPI_Send(array`.

Comment: also, the buffer to be passed to MPI is `buffer` and __not__ `&buffer`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet yes! thank you very much. I can't believe I didn't see that. Totally fixed!

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet You are right. I also didn't notice... I'll add this information to the answer. (Haven't been using C/C++ for a long time.)